# How to load viewController from a nib file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a Tab bar bases project (along with navigation control), inside a particular tab there is a tableViewLoaded , when i click on the table rows it shoud open another view , ie it pushes another controller , i have a view controller in the MainWindow.nib for this view also with some items like buttons labels , but whn i click it doesnt show up anythng only a blank page cums up , can any one help me out with this .

Answer (score 5):

You should generally use one view controller-per-nib file; it makes things much easier. A few things to check:

1. Is your view controller object being created (set a break point in its init, loadView, or viewDidLoad methods)
2. Is your view being displayed (set a breakpoint in your viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear: methods)
3. Is your view properly hooked up (make sure the view outlet in IB is hooked up correctly; this is a common mistake)

If your question is actually *how* to load a nib file that's paired with a UIViewController subclass, take a look at UIViewController's -initWithNibName:bundle: and -loadView methods.